# Why was the story watered down in Nobody Knows (2004, Japan)?

Tags: historical-accuracy, nobody-knows

The movie [Nobody Knows](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0408664/) was based on an actual event, which apparently was considerably more horrific ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugamo_child_abandonment_case)) than the story depicted in the movie.

So why did the director-writer choose to water it down? I found this curious, since this is the exact opposite of the usual practice (at least Hollywood) where movies based on true events are usually exaggerated.

Comment: I disagree with that last sentence, though. Hollywood *often* waters down true stories.

Comment: @Walt: Could you name me some examples of famous movies that were watered down? I'm not a movie aficionado and off the top of my head I couldn't think of any. One other movie I'd watched recently was Fargo, which despite starting off claiming to be based on a true story, was completely made up.